# Refresh page partially

Tags: visualforce, charts

Have created charts related to its tab. Scenario is there there are three tabs[Account,Leads and Forecast] .When i click on Accounts tab,it should display charts related to Accounts. Likewise when i click on Leads tab ,it displays chart related to Leads.

My problem is when i click from Accounts tab to Leads tab,whole page gets refreshed/loaded. Below is the code for Page  and controller.

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="PieChartController" title="Pie Chart">

<apex:tabPanel switchType="server" id="panel">

    <apex:tab label="Account" id="tab1">
       <apex:chart height="200" width="200" data="{!pieData}">
        <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name"/> 
        <apex:legend position="right">
        </apex:legend>
      </apex:chart>

      <apex:chart height="200" width="200" data="{!pieData}">
        <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name"/> 
          <apex:legend position="right">
        </apex:legend>

       </apex:chart>
    </apex:tab>



     <apex:tab label="Leads" id="tab2" reRender="">

        <script>
        var barData = [{'data':100, 'label':'UK'}, {'data':30, 'label':'France'}, {'data':55, 'label':'Spain'}, {'data':60, 'label':'Germany'}];
        </script> 

        <apex:chart data="barData" height="300px" width="300px">


            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" title="Nos Leads" grid="true" fields="data" minimum="0">
            </apex:axis>

            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="label" title="Country">
                <apex:chartLabel rotate="315"/>
            </apex:axis>

            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="label" yField="data"/>
        </apex:chart>
     </apex:tab>




     <apex:tab label="Forecast" id="tab3">

        <apex:chart name="AnnualRecurringRevenue" data="{!nvs}" width="400" height="400"
                colorSet="#156F9E,#FF9123,#6BAE4A,#424242,#A4A4A4">
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" grid="true" title="$(Millions)"
                    fields="v"/>
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" grid="false" title="Quarter"
                    fields="n"/>
            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="n" yField="v"
                    colorsProgressWithinSeries="true"/>
        </apex:chart>



         <apex:chart name="AnnualRecurringRevenue 2" data="{!nvs}" width="400" height="400"
                colorSet="#156F9E,#FF9123,#6BAE4A,#424242,#A4A4A4">
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" grid="true" title="$(Millions)"
                    fields="v"/>
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" grid="false" title="Quarter"
                    fields="n"/>
            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="n" yField="v"
                    colorsProgressWithinSeries="true"/>
        </apex:chart>



       <apex:chart name="AnnualRecurringRevenue 3" data="{!nvs}" width="400" height="400"
                colorSet="#156F9E,#FF9123,#6BAE4A,#424242,#A4A4A4">
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" grid="true" title="$(Millions)"
                    fields="v"/>
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" grid="false" title="Quarter"
                    fields="n"/>
            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="n" yField="v"
                    colorsProgressWithinSeries="true"/>
        </apex:chart>

   </apex:tab>
 </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class PieChartController {

    public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData()
   {
       List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Jan', 30));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Feb', 15));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Mar', 10));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Apr', 20));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('May', 20));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Jun', 5));
        return data;     

   }
// Wrapper class
  public class PieWedgeData 
  {
    public String name { get; set; }
    public Integer data { get; set; }

    public PieWedgeData(String name, Integer data) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }
    }


// 'N' for name and 'v' for value

 public class Nv {
        public String n { get; private set; }        
        public Decimal v { get; private set; }
        Nv(String n, Decimal v) {
            this.n = n;
            this.v = v;       
        }
    }
    public Nv[] getNvs() {
        return new Nv[] {
            new Nv('Actual', 106.00),
            new Nv('Forecast', 150.56),
            new Nv('Plan', 135.00),
            new Nv('Prior Qtr', 97.00),
            new Nv('Prior Yr', 88.44)
        };
    } 
}
```

Want that refresh should be only within the tabs when clicked on particular tab and not the whole page ?

Comment: First thing to try is to remove reRender="".

Comment: ... well it is present in the Visualforce you posted.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo mistake.Removed rerender,even then it is refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Fair enough; wasn't saying it was the answer, just the first thing to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `switchType` on your `apex:tabPanel` to "client".

**PS** This [How can you make a visualforce graph display correctly within a TabPanel?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23618/how-can-you-make-a-visualforce-graph-display-correctly-within-a-tabpanel) looks like it covers the same sort of page and the recommendation is to stick with `switchType` of "server". Perhaps you can add to your question what is problematic about the refresh you are getting at the moment.

Comment: No joy yet .When changing switchtype to "client" ,charts on both the tabs doesn't show.There is nothing that tab shows.Blank tab.

Comment: Yeah I've just tried it now and while the SVG looks OK in the second tab it doesn't draw properly. (The switchType="server" has a slight time delay when you switch tables but at least draws properly.)

Comment: so  switchtype="server" can only be the solution ? No problems with the refresh part,only want that it should be partially loaded.

Comment: Looking in the "Network" tab of Chrome's "Developer Tools" using "server" looks like it results in the whole page being reloaded. I know that perhaps isn't ideal, but why is it a problem?

Comment: Want to know for my knowledge improvement and better understanding, becasue using switchtype="server" whole page is loading which is taking time loading on to the server whereas what i want is only within the frame of that particular page it should get refreshed which is fast.Could you please help me out.

Comment: @user27 I'm afraid I don't know of a solution.